# Oracle regex match pattern ending with ABBA

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to be able to find strings that end with a pattern "ABBA", where
A - digit
B - digit, not equal to A.

Consider a string - 88889889 which matches the above pattern. Generally, I would use negative lookahead in other languages like below
[image]

But Oracle does not support negative lookahead. How can this be achieved in Oracle?
Oracle version:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0

I have tried implementing something like this:

```
select 1 "val"
 from dual
where regexp_like('88889889','\S+(\d)(\d)\2\1$');
```

However, it matches both 88889889 and 88889999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1:

You can compare the capturing group values to ensure that they are not equal:

```sql
SELECT value,
       1 "val"
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,'\S+(\d)(\d)\2\1$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
       <> REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,'\S+(\d)(\d)\2\1$', 1, 1, NULL, 2);
```

#### Option 2:

Or, with simple (faster) string functions:

```sql
SELECT value,
       1 "val"
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SUBSTR(value, -4, 1) = SUBSTR(value, -1, 1)
AND    SUBSTR(value, -3, 1) = SUBSTR(value, -2, 1)
AND    SUBSTR(value, -4, 1) <> SUBSTR(value, -3, 1);
```

#### Option 3:

Or, if you have Java enabled in the database then you can create a Java function to match regular expressions:

```sql
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED RegexParser AS
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexpMatch {
  public static int match(
    final String value,
    final String regex
  ){
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    return pattern.matcher(value).matches() ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
/
```

Then wrap it in an SQL function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION regexp_java_match(value IN VARCHAR2, regex IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'RegexpMatch.match( java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) return int';
/
```

Then use it in SQL:

```sql
SELECT value,
       1 "val"
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_JAVA_MATCH(value,'\S+(\d)(?!\1)(\d)\2\1$') = 1;
```

---

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '88889889' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '88889999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '88881234' FROM DUAL;
```

All three options output:

> | VALUE | val |
> | --- | --- |
> | 88889889 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4cbc19fa01842e2a83915ec807e911f0)*

Comment: +. Another option would be to use something like `WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(value,'\S*(\d)\1\d\d$') AND REGEXP_LIKE(value,'\S*(\d)(\d)\2\1$')`. But I don't know enough about Oracle to tell whether or not it's a valid option nor how it would compare against your options. I did read that lookahead's are not supported leading to these "double" executed functions.

Comment: @JvdV That would work [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0f37c8535fb426db17214e66dae653f2); however, you would need to check the performance of using two different regular expressions compared to using the same regular expression twice and extracting different capture groups. My guess is that 2 different regular expressions will be more expensive but that may not be the case in practice.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't *have to* be a regular expression, fairly simple conditional `substr` does the job:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 88889889 from dual union all  -- valid
  3     select 12345432 from dual union all  -- invalid
  4     select 443223   from dual union all  -- valid
  5     select 1221     from dual            -- valid
  6    ),
```

Just for simplicity, extract the last 4 digits (you'd, of course, discard all values that are shorter than 4 digits, right?):

```
  7  temp as
  8    (select col, substr(col, -4) last4
  9     from test
 10    )
```

Finally:

```
 11  select col,
 12    case when substr(last4, 1, 1) = substr(last4, 4, 1) and
 13              substr(last4, 2, 1) = substr(last4, 3, 1) then 'valid'
 14         else 'invalid'
 15    end result
 16  from temp;

       COL RESULT
---------- -------
  88889889 valid
  12345432 invalid
    443223 valid
      1221 valid

SQL>
```

Comment: And if has to be a regular expression?

Comment: Then you'll have to find someone who is good at it (I'm not).